# Android. Delete file after it has been shared

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I use this code to share a zip file (fzip):

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fzip));
    sendIntent.putExtra("myfilename", fzip.getPath());
    sendIntent.setType("application/zip");
    startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 1);
```

After the file is shared (copied, added to Dropbox, ...) I want to delete the original zip file because it is no longer useful.

I try to use this:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == 1) {

        String myname=data.getStringExtra("myfilename");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "created file:" + myname , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
    }
```

so that after I get the file name, and since the file has been shared, I could delete it.

The zip file is copied as it should. but the app crashes. What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us your crash log?

Comment: I have chosen to go with a different approach. Instead of trying to delete the file after it is shared, I will do what CommonsWare suggested, and delete it after some long period of time (next day for example). So I have done some changes in the code and the crash log is no more available. T

Answer (score 1):

First, `ACTION_SEND` is not used with `startActivityForResult()`, as it does not return a result.

Second, your extra is not on the `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()`, because those are separate `Intent` objects.

Third, just because control returned to you does not mean that the other application is done with your file yet. You have no good way to know when the other app is done with the file. I would recommend waiting 24 hours and deleting it then.

Comment: You suggest to put a timer that counts for long time and after that delete the zip file? I thought that but it didn't seem "elegant". I can not wait too long because the user may recreate and then re-share the zip file in a few seconds. How long do you think I should wait so that the file has reasonable time to get shared? The zip files are usually a few MB

Comment: @geo: That, or if you expect that the user will be in your app often enough, just check in your launcher activity if the file is old enough to warrant deletion. "I can not wait too long because the user may recreate and then re-share the zip file in a few seconds" -- use unique filenames. Also, store the files in a dedicated spot, perhaps in a subdirectory in `getExternalCacheDir()`, so it is easy for you to identify candidates for deletion.

Comment: @geo: "How long do you think I should wait so that the file has reasonable time to get shared?" -- there is no way to know for certain. For all you know, the other app will not send your file to some server until a nightly synchronization process. That's why I suggested 24 hours, as you're well into "it's the other app's problem" at that point, if the other app still needs it. With regards to "elegant", unfortunately, I am not aware of any elegant solution to this problem.